# Python - Django -Tastypie - How to run code after returning

Tags: python, django, tastypie

For the below code the return statement seems to execute only after the function has completed

```
def runJob(objects,bgJob):
   """DO SOME DJANGO STUFF"
   try:
       return prepareResponce(status=202)
   finally:
       runJob(objects, bgJob)
```

Basically I need to execute runJob after the return statement

Comment: then you need to create a celery task..

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special for tastypie or django here, this is how python works. As soon as you return value from function, it stops running.

So, the way to what you want is to start running so-called "background" or "async" task, launching it right before returning response to user.

This is well-known and solved problem. Toolset varies from casual [tastypie-async](https://github.com/miraculixx/tastypie-async) to heavy battle-proven production-ready [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Latter one has good integration with django + *huge* history in django community